# Scala XML extract the element in comma separator

Tags: scala, scala-xml

My Code

```
scala.xml.XML.loadString("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>" + line(1)).child
```

It will give me the list like this:

```
List(<c2>KH0011201</c2>, <c3>-1</c3>, <c4>380</c4>, <c7>50000</c7>, <c98/>)
```

I want to be like this

```
KH0011201, -1, 380, 50000, null
```

I have tried with:

```
scala.xml.XML.loadString("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>" + line(1)).child.text
```

but it gives me the line, cannot identified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `xml.Elem::text` method you've tried to use is indeed the right method to call, but you have to apply it on each child within a map transformation:

```
import scala.xml.Elem

List[Elem](<c2>KH0011201</c2>, <c3>-1</c3>, <c4>380</c4>, <c7>50000</c7>, <c98/>)
  .map(_.text)
// List[String] = List("KH0011201", "-1", "380", "50000", "")
```

Note that it transforms the value of the empty `<c98/>` element to `""` and not `null`.